# There any way to get de percentage of number of post by user and category?

Tags: categories, count

This is the thing, Id like to get the % of number of posts from a specific user and category, additionally choosing from 'n' last days, or get for 'n' posts.

Example:

- A: User 2 have a **10%** of total CARS category on last 15 days.
- B: User 2 have a **10** posts  for CARS category on last **20** CARS category posts.
- C: User 2 have a **10** posts for CARS category posted since 15 days ago.

Any of these examples, I think that knowing the correct code, the whatever result is easy to use.

I have next code, but, I get only % of TOTAL of post for selected category (I don't know how to choose from how many days ago or from how many posts of category):

```
function boz_tscount() {
    $args = array( 
        'author' => 2,
        'cat'    => 11,
    );
    $cat_total = get_category( 11 );
    $my_query  = new WP_Query( $args );
    $cat_count = $my_query->post_count;
    //get % = count / total * 100
    echo $cat_count / $cat_total->count * 100;
}
```